# How to stop AsyncTaskLoader from reloading

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

Currently building an Android app and utilizing AsyncTaskLoader. My app contains a ListView of articles that I obtain using JSON calls. It will leave and go somewhere else (in my case the browser) when the user clicks on an item, but when I press back it reloads the Loader. How can set it up to not reload? Thank you!

Comment: Try to cache your content and please put some code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     cancelLoadInBackground()
```

Method of AsyncTaskLoader class.

Comment: Here is a full document - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html